# How is isalnum() so efficient?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

In an XML parser I'm working on, I scan through whitespace using `isalnum` to test for characters. While trying to optimize the parser, I found `isalnum`'s efficiency to be rather surprising. I can parse my test file in ~500 ms when I using `isalnum`:

```
while (!isalnum(file[CurrentChar])) CurrentChar++;
```

---

NOTE: `file` is a string holding the XML document and `CurrentChar` is unsigned int holding the index of the `char` to be read in `file`.

---

However, somehow my parsing speed for the same file is ~1000 ms when I use this line instead:

```
while (file[CurrentChar]== ' ') CurrentChar++;
```

How is it that `isalnum` can test for 26+10 values and perform better than a single test for one value?

Comment: But those two lines of code do not do the same thing.  In particular, what is the value of CurrentChar after each?  And are you compiling with full optimization enabled?

Comment: Are you compiling with or without optimization. If without optimization, the compiler might be going strictly by the book with the comparison, and widening the character to an `int`, before comparing it to a space; but not with `isalnum()` which is likely to be a bit test in a fixed 256 byte lookup table.

Comment: isalnum() returns false for a lot of stuff in an XML file, such as `<` and `/` , surely your `file[CurrentChar]== '  '` logic can't be compared to that.

Comment: @nos This code is run after reading the name of a tag. Both lines successfully read through whitespace until an attribute or the end of the tag.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I have no optimization enabled.

Comment: So that's one possible explanation, the compiler is executing literal code to widen the char to an int, versus a bit test. Examine the resulting assembly language, from both versions, to confirm.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik After enabling optimizations I received near-equal performance.

Comment: Wonderful. Sounds like the books can be closed on this one, then...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the performance of unoptimized code, which is uninteresting and a waste of everyone's time. Besides, the asker has answered his own question, and the scenario is so narrowly-scoped that it will not be useful to anyone else in the future.

Comment: Not only is looking at unoptimized code pointless in general, it is _especially_ bad when comparing a standard library call with user-code, since the standard library call (unless inlined, which is rare) is going to be the same fully optimized version regardless of how you compile your code, while the user code will get the full benefit or disadvantage from your optimization settings.

Comment: The behavior depends also on CPU, compiler and options, ...